# how to implement IObjectSafety to my webpage page

Tags: javascript, html, vb6, activex

i have a  java-script function (in my html page) that uses active code. i searched in google and found out that i need to implement IObjectSafety to my webpage in order to stop the activex propmt saying "Active X control on this page might be unsafe to interact , Y/N ?" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this by marking this control as being safe for scripting.  Do this in the VB6 Package and Deployment wizard.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733548(v=VS.60).aspx

If you really must implement this interface, you'll need a type library editor, or an IDL/ODL compiler.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182598

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224(VS.85).aspx